# Why do I get two console logs while its should be just one ? react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, web-component

I have a simple section in react which contains two buttons logo and banner, on click I am opening a simple modal from web component, now I want when user click cancel to show me something on the console.

Problem: When I click eg Logo button which opens the modal and I click cancel I get the console log I want, and then I click the banner button and open the modal and I click cancel, instead of giving just logs related to the banner button I get both of logs.

my code Live demo : [live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-haze-mxj7t?file=/src/Images.js)

```
import * as element from "./custom-element";

const Images = () => {
  const [imgName, setImgName] = useState();
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState();
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState();
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  const handleUseImage = () => {
    switch (imgName) {
      case "logo":
        console.log("logo name", imgName);
        break;
      case "banner":
        console.log("banner name", imgName);
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (imgName) {
      elementRef.current.addEventListener("cancel", function (e) {
        handleUseImage(e);
      });
    }
  }, [imgName]);

  const handleLogo = () => {
    setImgName("logo");
    openModal();
  };
  const handleBanner = () => {
    setImgName("banner");
    openModal();
  };
  const openModal = () => {
    elementRef.current.visible = true;
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <custom-element ref={elementRef}></custom-element>
      <button onClick={handleLogo}>Logo </button>
      <button onClick={handleBanner}>Banner </button>
      <span>Logo url: {logo} </span>
      <span>banner url: {banner} </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Images;
```

[[image]][2

Why do I get both logs?

Comment: You are adding a new event listener every time the imageName changes in useEffect. Each one calls `handleUseImage()` . You need to remove prior listener before adding a new one or change the logic of a single event listener

Comment: 1. Don't mix DOM manipulation with React. 2. If you absolutely must at least remove it with the cleanup function you return to `useEffect` because otherwise you're leaking memory with *every single re-render*. Your problem is most likely that the event listener callback is closing over the stale value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure the issue is that you never remove the event listener, so when you call `setImgName` it will rerender, and now you'll have *two* event listeners, one which is "out of scope" (for lack of a better term - it doesn't have the the "current" state values, as it was from a previous render).  I would try

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (imgName) {
    elementRef.current.addEventListener("cancel", handleUseImage);
    return () => {
        elementRef.current.removeEventListener("cancel", handleUseImage);
    }
  }
}, [imgName]);
```

Comment: Yup. Stale closure. That's why you don't mix DOM manipulations and React.

Comment: @JaredSmith in the real app we have shareable components which is used in multiple small apps into big one , that is why we are using web components like youtube does

Comment: @TheDeadMan Nothing wrong with mixing webcomponents and React, it's the imperative DOM manipulations that don't play nice with React.

Comment: @JaredSmith agreed but so far we don't have another solution, maybe u can share ur experience, assume u have five small apps into a big one and u have a section in which all of those apps are using eg modal share, what solution will you provide here? so that developers can share this modal (code)?